# Is it possible to have the opened application bar on top with the launcher bar (Gnome Metacity)

Tags: gnome, metacity

I would like to have the opened windows bar on the top as a second bar fused with the launcher bar in Gnome Classic without Effects (presumably aka Gnome metacity). Is it possible to configure it like so?

It make no sense to split application manipulation along two completely opposite sides of the screen. Windows for example facilitates this by facilitating multiple lines of taskbar, namely one line for quicklaunch and the other for the opened applications which is my objective as specified.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the bar to the top.